# jQuery allow scrolling through various LI elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created a ribbon in HTML / jQuery of which an implementation can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/Complexity/qwV84/

In the native Office applications (Word, Excel, Powerpoint, ...), when you're mouse cursor is placed over the tabs and you scroll the next tab is showed.

Through javascript I've already created an API that allows me to show the tab contents of a given tab:

```
EnableTabContents: function() {

// Start by deactiving every tab element on the page.
$("li[role=tab]").each(function(index) {
  $(this).removeClass("active");
  $(".contents", this).removeClass("active");
});

// Activate the tab which is requested.
$(this).addClass("active");
$(".contents", this).addClass("active");

// Return the "tab" element.
return $(this);
},
```

But, now I want to achieve to activate the tabs based on scrolling.

So, bascilly, I have 2 questions:

- How can I determine that my mouse cursor is placed on the ribbon?
- How to implement the scroll event in jQuery only when my cursor where I want it to be?

I know that there is the mouseenter event in jQuery, but isn't it very painfull to set an event handler in an event?
As an alternative, I could set a variable and in the scroll event chech if the variable has the appropriate value.

For the ones intrested in the project, it's open source:

https://github.com/Kevin-De-Coninck/OfficeWebControls

Thanks for the advice.

Comment: have you looked into using .mouseover() ?
You could create a mouseover function which displays/hides certain tabs when you hover over a particular tab http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

Comment: I've done it, but I want to be able to scroll it to hide elements or not. I've updated the question as well.

Comment: I would use your second proposed approach, if for no other reason than readability and maintainability.  I'm just not sure that there's a scroll event that you can attach to if the element doesn't actually "scroll."  I think that the scroll event fires when there is a delta in the x or y position.  Would be interested to know how you solve this.

Comment: When I find a solution I would place it here, so make sure to mark this question as your favorite :-)

Comment: Solution has been found. I've answered my own question. So it might help you sooner or later :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

After some searching, I've found the solution to this question.
For the persons who are instrested, here's the solution:

There's a browser event called [DOMMouseScroll](http://help.dottoro.com/ljqeknfl.php), which only works in Firefox.
Luckally, there is an alternative event which support Google Chrome and Internet Explorer just fine, called [OnMouseWheel](http://help.dottoro.com/ljmracjb.php).

Note: The direction of the scroll wheel is reversed in both events, in the DOMMouseScroll, we need to check if the detail of the originalEvent is larger than 0 to identify scrolling down.
In OnMouseWheel, the wheelDelta of the original event should be smaller than 0 to identify scrolling down.

Anywere, to scroll between the various tabs, the following code is used:

Firefox:

```
    $("#ribbon").bind('DOMMouseScroll', function(e){
        if(e.originalEvent.detail > 0) {
            // Actives the tab that is the next element.
            var nextTab = $("li[role=tab].active").next();
            var attribute = $(nextTab).attr('role');

            if (attribute == 'tab') {
                $(nextTab).EnableTabContents();
            }

        }else {
            // Actives the tab that is the previous element.
            var previousTab = $("li[role=tab].active").prev();
            var attribute = $(previousTab).attr('role');

            if (attribute == 'tab' && !$(previousTab).hasClass('application')) {
                $(previousTab).EnableTabContents();
            }
        }

        //prevent page fom scrolling
        return false;
    });
```

And for Google Chrome and Internet Explorer (should work in Safari and Opera to but I haven't tested it):

```
    $("#ribbon").bind('mousewheel', function(e){
        if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {
            // Actives the tab that is the next element.
            var nextTab = $("li[role=tab].active").next();
            var attribute = $(nextTab).attr('role');

            if (attribute == 'tab') {
                $(nextTab).EnableTabContents();
            }

        } else {
            // Actives the tab that is the previous element.
            var previousTab = $("li[role=tab].active").prev();
            var attribute = $(previousTab).attr('role');

            if (attribute == 'tab' && !$(previousTab).hasClass('application')) {
                $(previousTab).EnableTabContents();
            }
        }

        //prevent page fom scrolling
        return false;
    });
```

In my examples above you have some additional logic to make sure that I'm scrolling to a Tab element and that that element is not the application tab.

You see I'm using the EnableTabContents() function. This is my own function and it part of the API and it just sets the necesarry elements visible or invisible, no I will not post that code here.

I hope it can help anyone in the future :-)

Comment: Awesome, I learned something today.  Any reason for the use of the deprecated bind method and not on()?  And, did you separate these into two handlers just for clarity in this answer or did it not work by passing both events into the same handler?  P.S. you should mark your answer as correct btw.

Comment: First of all, I will accept my own answer tomorrow since I have to wait until then. Then I didn't know that the bind method was deprecated (where did you find it) so I will likely change it to use the On() method. Also, I didn't know that you could pass multiple events into a single event handler. I'm not that good at jQuery. But thanks for those remarks. I will probably change the code to include your remarks.

Comment: You know what, technically, bind is not deprecated. I misspoke. It's the live method that was deprecated and later removed.  Nonetheless, on() is described as the "preferred" method in the doc since 1.7. Probably because it handles delegation without the use of a separate method (i.e. live/delegate) or maybe b/c it's closer to vanilla JS (onclick, onerror...).  And, yeah, you can pass multiple events to it like this: $('someselector').on('click tap', ... The event names are just space-separated.  Anyway, I was just curious and I think your ribbon is very cool.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable information. In case you're intrested in my Ribbon, you can check out the source on Github: https://github.com/Kevin-De-Coninck/OfficeWebControls However, there still some bugs to make the document fully W3C but I'm working on it. If you're planning to use it, let me know what you think of it.